# How to bake static Unit scene into one big mesh and texture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a big complex unity scene including terrain, trees, grass, flowers and many other objects.

I'm having performance problems and i was wondering if its possible to bake all static objects that never move or change like terrain trees, houses, and other props etc, into one big static object to increase performance?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for a draw call optimizer, check out asset store like this one https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16538

Comment: is "Unit" a new game engine ???

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Unity documentation on Static Objects [here.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html)

> Many optimisations need to know if an object can move during gameplay. Information about a Static (ie, non-moving) object can often be precomputed in the editor in the knowledge that it will not be invalidated by a change in the object’s position. For example, rendering can be optimised by combining several static objects into a single, large object known as a batch.

To mark a GameObject as static, you simply need to check the Static box in the inspector window with the desired GameObject selected.

Comment: no dude .. the questioner is asking about **Unit**.  It's that new competitor to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't be a good idea. Having separate meshes is much more beneficial and efficient than combining them all into one huge mesh. This will allow you to set different LOD systems for the objects, billboarding of trees and detail objects, and will allow for finer control over your scene without having to rebuild that huge object again and again.

For large scenes, it is important that you set up a Level Of Detail (LOD) system. What it essentially means is that based on the distance of the object from the camera, a higher or lower quality model of that object will be rendered. At close distances, the highest polygon model will be rendered. At huge distances where detail is not required, lower polygon count models can be used. Consult [the Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html) for more details. You can also look for scripts and tutorials on the internet.

Also, make sure that your terrain settings are reasonable. Setting the Pixel Error of the terrain to 1 is overkill, something like 4-5 is more than enough. Detail Density, Billboard Start, Detail and Tree Distance all these can be toned down.

Or just check for an unoptimized script or shader gone awry, that's usually the problem. Unoptimized 3d models are hell too. You'll have to do more than just pick up a model from Sketchup's 3D warehouse (speaking from personal experience). You will *have* to pay an artist to get high quality, optimized models with their LOD meshes also unless you have the skills yourself.